# What do you call the person you have assigned a delegate for?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an antonym for “delegate”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/is-there-an-antonym-for-delegate)

*Person A* is a **delegate** (makes decisions for) for *Person B* while *Person B* is gone.  What would you call *Person B*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the scenario you described the person B would be a [*principal*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/principal):

> 3) (law) One who directs another (the agent) to act on one's behalf
>
> > When an attorney represents a client, the client is the principal who permits the attorney, the client's agent, to act on the client's behalf.