# Is there an antonym for the verb form of delegate?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

This question seeks an antonym for the noun form: [Is there an antonym for “delegate”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7709/35993)
I seek an antonym for the act of delegating, where instead of passing work or authority to another to keep it for for yourself.
I would also accept single words for taking on work/authority from a subordinate, whether it had previously been explicitly delegated or not.

Comment: It's not always *quite* the same thing, but in many contexts [*micromanagement*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanagement) is effectively the opposite of *delegation*. The underlying motivation is the same in both cases (boss doesn't trust subordinates to do things properly).

Comment: It's also not quite the same thing, but to _arrogate_ authority is to unjustly seize it for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [centralise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centralize): (from M-W)

> - to bring (something) under the control of one authority

Answer (score 1):

To "retain" - verb - continue to have (something); keep possession of

Retain might work for authority or power.  It doesn't work as well for work or tasks.