# What is the word for a person who delegates their vote?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a delegation system. Users can hand over their votes to delegates (the noun). I am wondering what is the opposite of a 'delegate'.

> I just delegated my vote to John, now he has a new ________.

I looked around, and found 'delegator' but I'm not sure if it's the right word.

If *delegate* is confusing or wrong in this context, I also found 'delegatee' and 'representative'.

Comment: Does [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50796/what-is-the-inverse-term-for-a-proxy/50799#50799) help any?

Comment: I think we need to know what "delegation" means in this case. Is your delegate really a proxy?

Comment: The opposite of "delegate" is to not delegate.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/is-there-an-antonym-for-delegate?rq=1) as well.

Comment: @BrianHooper Thanks, "principal" seems to be appropriate in the context of the law

Comment: @AndrewLeach: In my case, it's a voting system (aka: [delegative democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegative_democracy)) where users delegates their votes to other users.

Comment: I also found [constituents](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/7714/67121) in the answers you provided which is pretty good

Comment: From the context in your question, I don't think you are looking for an antonym. You seem to be looking for the word for a person who delegates their vote (a delegator, as you have suggested) in contrast to the person to whom votes are delegated (which is what the noun *delegate* describes). I have edited your question to reflect that. You may rollback the edit if that was not your intent.

Answer (score 2):

I think I will settle with delegatee/delegator:

> I just delegated my vote to John, now he has a new *delegator*.

Comment: The 2 words fit, i.e. *a delegator delegates his vote to a delegatee*. However, I won't say that  "John has a new delegator": he rather *has a proxy of a new delegator*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***proxy giver***.

> The person who grants the power is called a proxy giver. The person who receives the power is called a proxy holder. A proxy is a form of agency. The proxy giver consents to the proxy holder's voting the share for her [Shade's Business Associations in a Nutshell](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AzvaCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT168&dq=%22proxy+giver%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixmPze_IHKAhVHpA4KHV6qCGUQ6AEIPzAD#v=onepage&q=%22proxy%20giver%22&f=false)
>
> *I just delegated my vote to John, now he has a new proxy giver.*
>
> *Respond when the name of your proxy giver is called* [Roll Call](http://wiki.democratsabroad.org/download/attachments/10585112/RollCall2015.pdf?api=v2)